# How can I make 2 dimensional array using mixed type in c program?

Tags: arrays, c

Roma    I V X  L    C   D   M
arabia  1   5   10  50  100 500 1000

I want to make 2 dimensional array which include characters and integers to convert roma to arabia number.

```
enter code here

void roma_signal(){ 

char ary1[7]={'I','V','X','L','C','D','M'};
int ary2[7]={1,5,10,50,100,500,1000};
char *ptr_ary[2]={ary1, ary2}; 
int i, j;
for(i=0; i<2; i++){
    for(j=0; j<7; j++){
        printf("%5d", ptr_ary[i][j]);
        }
printf("₩n");
    }

}
```

so I made this table , but it doesn't work ....

[image: In line 40, cannot convert int* to char *]

In line 40, error :cannot convert int* to char *  .....

1. why this happens?
2. How can I make this table using pointer ?

Comment: You may want to read this: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12149471)

Comment: Sounds like you want an array of structs.

Comment: In an array, all elements must be of the same type. If you want a type which can contain different types, you can use a `struct`. You can also create an array of these `struct`s. But what is wrong with having two separate arrays? That seems ideal in your situation.

Comment: `int*` to `char*` conversion is generally not permitted because although pointer variables themselves are of same size, the dereferenced memory location will not. To prevent future mess, compilers won't allow that!

Comment: What if you use string and store everything you want in string